# AKS Cluster upgrade is failing

Tags: azure, azure-aks

I am trying to upgrade my cluster from v1.23.9 to v1.24.10. Azure asks me to apply Service Principle, which again requires me to enable manage identity. When I try to enable manage identity, it automatically starts cluster upgrade and the upgrade fails. I'm stuck in this loop.

I have checked all the settings and configurations in the Azure Portal, but I am unable to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade, firstly check available versions in AKS cluster hosted location using the below command.

```
az aks get-versions --location eastus
```

[image]

Next , use az aks upgrade command, to upgrade the kubernetes cluster.

```
az aks upgrade --resource-group <resource-group-name> --name <aks-cluster-name> --kubernetes-version <version-number>
```

[image]

Now verify the AKS version under properties session.
[image]

Comment: @Vikram Giriraj, did it work?